# composer psr-4 автозагрузка классов, Class 'TestApp\Converter' not found

Tags: php, composer, slim, autoload

Хотел реализовать автозагрузку классов, но
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура каталогов:

```
api 
--index.php
--converter.php
vendor
composer.json
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "slim/slim": "3.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr4": {
            "TestApp\\": "api/"
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
namespace TestApp;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config['displayErrorDetails'] = true;

$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);

$app->get('/{id_page}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    if(!$request->getAttribute('has_errors')){
        $response->getBody()->write(Converter::getJsonByFileName(2));
    }
    else{
        $response->getBody()->write($request->getAttribute('errors'));
    }
    return $response;

});
$app->run();
```

converter.php

```
<?php
namespace TestApp;
class Converter{
    static function getFileName($filename){
        return $filename;
    }
}
?>
```

Любые попытки поиграть с пространствами имен успеха не приносят

Comment: Всё логично. Не находит класс т.к. вы use не прописали

Comment: @InDevX, можете пожалуйста поподробнее описать, где и как его надо прописать? Потому что я с ним тоже много экспериментировал, и у меня ничего не получилось, похожая ошибка

Comment: Для файлов лежащих в одном каталоге и имеющие одинаковый namespace использование use не обязательно!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените psr4 на psr-4 и не забудьте выполнить php composer.phar update

```
 {
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "slim/slim": "3.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TestApp\\": "api/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В `index.php` namespace указывать не нужно.

Для неймспейса лучше выделить отдельную директорию (и, желательно, на уровень выше докрута),

Структура каталогов примерно такая:

```
public <- Вот это должно быть докрутом для apache/nginx/etc
  index.php
src
  Converter.php <- Соблюдаем регистр, т.к. сервер скорее всего будет на Linux и там регистр важен
vendor
composer.json
```

В `composer.json` указывавем (как уже заметили, меняем `psr4` на `psr-4`):

```json
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "slim/slim": "3.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TestApp\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге `public/index.php` будет выглядеть так:

```php
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config['displayErrorDetails'] = true;

$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);

$app->get('/api/{id_page}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    if(!$request->getAttribute('has_errors')){
        $response->getBody()->write(Converter::getJsonByFileName(2));
    }
    else{
        $response->getBody()->write($request->getAttribute('errors'));
    }
    return $response;

});
$app->run();
```

и `src/Converter.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace TestApp;

class Converter
{
    static function getFileName($filename)
    {
        return $filename;
    }
}
```

Стоит заметить, что закрывающий тег php `?>` в  конце файлов классов - плохая практика

Ну и напоследок - новые приложения всё же лучше писать на 4 версии slim)